# Close all Snip & Sketch windows, without having to save/discard for every window

Tags: windows-10, snipping, snipping-tool

If I'm writing a Confluence article, I'll often use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, grab what I want, highlight a piece of the image with the editing tool, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it so I can paste it into my article. When I'm done, I then have a bunch of Snip & Sketch windows open.

How can I close all the Snip & Sketch windows without having to say `Don't save` on them individually, and without having to End Task on the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I close all the Snip & Sketch windows without having to say
> Don't save on them individually,

Natively in Windows you cannot. Too many people did not save their work that Microsoft has enforced Must Save before Exit.

You would see if you can write an Auto Hotkey script to do this.

I just have developed the habit to save and then exit. It saves time overall.

Comment: Thanks John. I may end up moving back to SnagIt instead.

Comment: SnagIt also requires you to Save if you must exit Snagit Editor. I use the latest version of Snagit myself.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to use DangIt instead then (dang-it, i need to click don't save x times)

Answer (score 0):

A brute-force solution is to just terminate the entire Snip & Sketch application from Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can add snip and sketch to your windows taskbar, then hover/click over it and close all the individual open windows when they display their thumbnails.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That doesn't work, because each window displays a save & close dialog which doesn't come into focus.